# multiple Gruntfilejs files

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm new to `bower` and `grunt` and I just started my first project with the below bower dependancies:

bower.json

```
    {
       "name": "test",
       "version": "0.0.0",
       "authors": [
       ""
       ],
       "license": "MIT",
       "ignore": [
       "**/.*",
       "node_modules",
       "bower_components",
       "test",
       "tests"
       ],
       "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-rtl": "~0.9.1",
        "jquery-ui-bootstrap": "~0.2.5",
        "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
        "jquery": "~2.0.3"
        },
        "exportsOverride": {
            "*": {
                "js": "**/*.js",
                "css": "**/*.css"
            }
        }
    }
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: './lib',
                    layout: 'byType',
                    install: true,
                    verbose: false,
                    cleanTargetDir: false,
                    cleanBowerDir: false,
                    bowerOptions: {}
                }
            }
        }
        //--end
    });
    // Load plugins here
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');



    // Define your tasks here
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['bower']);


};
```

I noticed that `bower_components/bootstrap-rtl/` contains another `Gruntfile.js`.

Is there away to call `bower_components/bootstrap-rtl/Gruntfile.js` from my `Gruntfile.js`  before the `bower:install`?

Comment: why would you want to call their `Gruntfile`?

Comment: i want to build bootstrap-rtl while building building my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--gruntfile` to determine the location of the Gruntfile.

Check out the [CLI source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/bin/grunt#L27) for more info.

Example use:

```
grunt jshint --gruntfile bower_components/bootstrap-rtl/Gruntfile.js
```

You could also use [grunt-grunt](https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-grunt), which I just wrote for this kind of scenario.

You configure it like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    grunt: {
        boots: {
            gruntfile: 'bower_components/bootstrap-rtl/Gruntfile.js',
            tasks: ['some', 'tasks']
        }
    }
});
```

Then you could just set up an alias, such as below:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['grunt:boots', 'compile']);
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I want to be able to build both projects with a single call to my gruntjs file. The same way Ant does for compiling dependent java projects.

Comment: Wrote a grunt plugin that does that for you :) [grunt-grunt](https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-grunt), see updated answer